# Remove non-numeric characters at the start of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to get the value from an input field, find the first number on it, and remove everything else BEFORE the number.

But I need to leave the number (and anything after it) as it is.

I tried some options, but couldn't do it.

Any ideas?

I managed to find where is the first number. But when I try to remove everything BEFORE it, I endup removing the first number as well, or removing another stuff (like periods and commas)

Here is how I got the first number position:

```
$stringPrice = '__.500,00';
if(preg_match('/[0-9]/', $stringPrice, $positionNum, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    echo "First number is at " . $positionNum[0][1];
} else {
    echo "Invalid value";
}
```

Comment: People downvote because you dont show anything you attempted to do.
It's not nice to help people that didn't try. If you have some code, show it and people will gladly help you

Comment: I tried with regex and preg-match, that's why I used 'em as related subjects. Why not ask for the code before downvoting, if that is the problem?

Comment: I didn't downvote, i just explain to you why people downvote here. You say you have tried, just past your attempt here and everybody will be happy :)

Comment: Already did.
And I was not pointing the finrget at you. Just generally asking why.

Comment: Everything is ok, but you don't try all methods to manipulate string. You have functions like substr,  strpos etc.

Comment: Just use [`preg_replace('/^\D+/', '', $stringPrice);`](https://ideone.com/HGx94K)

Comment: I was trying that with 'd' instead of 'd+'. thnx for the reply Wiktor, can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current issue is to remove all non-numeric chars from the start of the string up to the first digit.

Use

```
preg_replace('/^\D+/', '', $stringPrice);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/HGx94K)

The `^` makes sure matching starts at the start of the string and `\D+` matches one or more chars other than digits.

Comment: Was trying that with 'd' instead of 'd+'.